# Have a NC relay open

Tags: relay, switching

I have an unfortunate situation where a large amount of devices are behind a few dozens NC relays. When power is applied the current spike is so large that the devices do not come up. I can't change the architecture of this solution. The relays were originally installed to be able to power cycle a group of devices. What I can do is rewire the relays to be NC and then switch each group of devices one by one to remove the large spikes.

Is it safe to have the NO connection essentially be closed for indefinite amounts of time?

Comment: There is probably a very specific reason for using nc relays. Did the system ever work?  As for what is ‘safe’, you’ve not told us much about the system. As for having relays permanently activated, most are perfectly happy with that. Check the relay datasheet.

Comment: It's *switching* that degrades a relay; holding a constant state doesn't damage anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A N.O. contact, when closed, intrinsically means "power is good."

This is often used in safety applications.  Consider an emergency-stop on a machine: voltage is present (usually 24VDC) and if this ever ceases, the entire machine is instantly shut down.  So a relay (or several relays, switches, sensors etc.) are often placed in series with this such that *all of them* must be in the correct state for the machine to run.

We have little idea how your relays are exactly wired and what they are supposed to do. But do consider that changing the way the relays work could have a negative impact on the safety performance of the machine.

The best solution sounds like the power feed should be improved (by an electrician) to supply enough current to start everything at once.  That way the operation of the machine/device is unchanged.

An alternative may be to add a simple toggle switch in series with the affected relay's coils.  Such that all of the toggle switches can be "off" and main power applied, and nothing happens.  Then as each toggle switch is closed, each relay closes, powering up only that section.  This may or may not work well, or may need a certain sequence/timing, depending on what those relays are controlling.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's safe to have the NO connection of a relay closed indefinitely. They are designed for that. I've never heard of one that wasn't designed for that. Of course, the coil uses power whenever it is closed, if that matters to you; if you have put the relay in a place where heat can build up, then heat can build up.